# How can I disable a section in Kivy settings?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, settings

I have a kivy app with settings and I wish to disable some settings (for example 'General') for certain users. I have tried to 'walk' through the children of settings (to use the disabled setting) but I cannot seem to do so.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.settings import SettingsWithSidebar
import json

settings_general = json.dumps([
    {'type': 'title',
     'title': 'Set general preferences'},
    {'type': 'bool',
     'title': 'Use widgets',
     'desc': 'Allow the use of widgets in the application',
     'section': 'general',
     'key': 'use widgets'},
    {'type': 'bool',
     'title': 'Print log',
     'desc': 'Print log on closing application',
     'section': 'general',
     'key': 'print log'}
     ])

settings_appearance = json.dumps([
    {'type': 'title',
     'title': 'Appearance preferences'},
    {'type': 'bool',
     'title': 'Use colour',
     'desc': 'Allow the use of colour in the application',
     'section': 'appearance',
     'key': 'use colour'}
     ])

class MainFrame(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        pass

    def on_settings_button_click(self):
        settings = self.app.settings_cls
        print('type settings', type(settings))
        print('is SettingsWithSidebar', isinstance(settings, 
                                                   SettingsWithSidebar))
        self.app.open_settings()

    def on_quit_button_click(self):
        quit()

class Settings(object):
    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('general',
            {
            'use widgets': 0,
            'print log': 0
            })
        config.setdefaults('appearance',
            {
            'use colour': 0
            })

    def build_settings(self, parent, settings):
        settings.add_json_panel('General',
                                parent.config,
                                data=settings_general)
        settings.add_json_panel('Appearance',
                                parent.config,
                                data=settings_appearance)

class BasicApp(App):
    def build(self):
        main_frame = MainFrame()
        main_frame.app = self
        self.settings_cls = SettingsWithSidebar
        self.use_kivy_settings = False
        return main_frame

    def build_config(self, config):
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.settings.build_config(config)

    def build_settings(self, settings):
        self.settings.build_settings(self, settings)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BasicApp().run()
```

My kv file is:

```
<MainFrame>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'Settings'
            on_press: root.on_settings_button_click()
        Button:
            text: 'Click to close'
            on_press: root.on_quit_button_click()
```

Can someone please suggest an approach that I can use?

[This section does not need to be read]
I have to enter more text before I am allowed to post this (ratio of code to text I think). It seems a shame because the question is so simple and I wanted to provide a basic working example of the application which is, of necessity, quite verbose. 
[end of extra text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the items in a panel with the `disabled` attribute.

```
settings_general = json.dumps([
    {'type': 'title',
     'title': 'Set general preferences'},
    {'type': 'bool',
     'disabled': True,
     'title': 'Use widgets',
     'desc': 'Allow the use of widgets in the application',
     'section': 'general',
     'key': 'use widgets'}])
```

The second item is disabled in this example.

However, I did not find an intuitive way to disable the whole `Appearance` section, for example.
So I went for a hackery method.
First was to walk the `settings` widget tree, to find that label.

```
tab = list(self.app.settings.walk(loopback=True))[5]
```

I found out that the label is the 6th element in this case.
But it was not enough to set `disable` attribute to `True`. It grays the label out, but it still works to click it, since they used the `on_touch_down` method.
So we can override the `on_touch_down` method.
I added a switch to the mainframe and a toggle method in the app class, to test this.

```
<MainFrame>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'Settings'
            on_press: root.on_settings_button_click()
        Switch:
            on_active: app.toggle_setting(self.active)
        Button:
            text: 'Click to close'
            on_press: root.on_quit_button_click()
```

[I found the original on_touch_down method here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/settings.py#L1235)

```
def on_touch_down(touch, self):
        # we need to write this method to override back to the original method
        # the original method was found in kivy/uix/settings.py.
        # look at the link above
        if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return
        self.selected = True
        self.menu.selected_uid = self.uid

class MainFrame(Screen):

    def on_settings_button_click(self):
        self.app.open_settings()
        tab = list(self.app.settings.walk(loopback=True))[5]
        if not self.app.toggle:  # if switch is inactive
            tab.disabled = True
            tab.on_touch_down = lambda x: False
        else:
            tab.disabled = False
            # we need partial from functools, so we can pass the tab as self
            tab.on_touch_down  = partial(on_touch_down,self=tab)


    def on_quit_button_click(self):
        quit()
```

The complete code:

```python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.settings import SettingsWithSidebar
from kivy.lang import Builder
import json
from functools import partial

settings_general = json.dumps([
    {'type': 'title',
     'title': 'Set general preferences'},
    {'type': 'bool',
     'disabled': True,
     'title': 'Use widgets',
     'section': 'general',
     'key': 'use widgets'}
     ])

settings_appearance = json.dumps([
    {'type': 'title',
     'title': 'Appearance preferences'},
    {'type': 'bool',
     'title': 'Use colour',
     'section': 'appearance',
     'key': 'use colour'}
     ])


def on_touch_down(touch, self):
        if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return
        self.selected = True
        self.menu.selected_uid = self.uid

class MainFrame(Screen):

    def on_settings_button_click(self):
        self.app.open_settings()
        tab = list(self.app.settings.walk(loopback=True))[5]
        if not self.app.toggle:
            tab.disabled = True
            tab.on_touch_down = lambda x: False
        else:
            tab.disabled = False
            tab.on_touch_down  = partial(on_touch_down,self=tab)


    def on_quit_button_click(self):
        quit()


Builder.load_string("""
<MainFrame>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'Settings'
            on_press: root.on_settings_button_click()
        Switch:
            on_active: app.toggle_setting(self.active)
        Button:
            text: 'Click to close'
            on_press: root.on_quit_button_click()
""")

class BasicApp(App):
    toggle = False

    def build(self):
        self.main = MainFrame()
        self.main.app = self
        self.settings_cls = SettingsWithSidebar
        self.use_kivy_settings = False
        return self.main

    def build_config(self, config):
        self.config = config
        self.config.setdefaults('general',{'use widgets': 0,'print log': 0})
        self.config.setdefaults('appearance',{'use colour': 0})

    def build_settings(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings
        self.settings.add_json_panel('General', self.config, data=settings_general)
        self.settings.add_json_panel('Appearance', self.config, data = settings_appearance)

    def toggle_setting(self, active):
        self.toggle = active


BasicApp().run()
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. Not trivial. I would never have found it

Comment: No that took a little look at the source code. That said, maybe I could make a PR to add a disabled feature to the panels, so it will become easier.